# Scaffold en flutter no cubre el 100% de la altura de la pantalla

Tags: flutter

No logro conseguir que mi app en flutter ocupe la altura total de la pantalla en el simulador de IOS.(Iphone XS - 12.2)
¿Puede ser que me falte alguna configuración?.
Dejare una imagen de ejemplo,
Muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Añado el código de la página inicial para mas información.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
// Import propios
import 'package:flutter_widgets/providers/menu_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widgets/src/utils/icon_string_util.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Widgets')), 
          body: _lista());
    }

    Widget _lista() {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future: menuProvider.cargarData(),
            initialData: [],
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                return ListView(
                    children: _listaItems(snapshot.data, context),
                );
            },
        );
    }

    List<Widget> _listaItems(List<dynamic> data, BuildContext context) {
        return data.map((opt) {
            return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                        title: Text(opt['texto']),
                        subtitle: Text(opt['ruta']),
                        leading: getIcon(opt['icon']),
                        trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right, color: Colors.deepOrange),
                        onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, opt['ruta']);
                        },
                    ),
                    Divider()
                ],
            );
        }).toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que estás usando ?

Comment: Hola, En mi caso me pasa desde que se crea el proyecto de flutter. Sin haber editado nada, ya me sale así al iniciar la app de contador que viene por defecto.De todas formas  subiré el código que tengo de la página inicial. Gracias!

Comment: Como llamas a la ruta de ese HomePage? A simple vista da la impresion de que hubiera un SafeArea por encima.

Comment: Si simulas otro iphone?